# Java byte array replace all occurrences of byte-array/string

Tags: java, arrays, line-endings

Is there any "already-implemented" (not manual) way to replace all occurrences of single byte-array/string inside byte array ? I have a case where i need to create byte array containing platform dependent text (Linux (line feed), Windows (carriage return + line feed)). I know such task can be implemented manually but i am looking for out-of-the-box solution. Note that these byte array's are large and solution needs to be performance wise in my case. Also note that i am processing large amount of these byte-arrays.

My current approach:

```
var byteArray = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:File.txt").getInputStream().readAllBytes();
byteArray = new String(byteArray)
    .replaceAll((schemeModel.getOsType() == SystemTypes.LINUX) ? "\r\n" : "\n",
                (schemeModel.getOsType() == SystemTypes.LINUX) ? "\n" : "\r\n"
    ).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This approach is not performance wise because of creating new Strings and using regex to find occurrences. I know that manual implementation would require looking at sequence of bytes because of Windows encoding. Manual implementation would therefore also require reallocation (if needed) as well.

Appache common lang utils contains `ArrayUtils` which contains method
`byte[] removeAllOccurrences(byte[] array, byte element)`. Is there any third party library which contains similar method for replacing **ALL** byte-arrays/strings occurrences inside byte array ??

**Edit**: As @saka1029 mentioned in comments, my approach doesn't work for Windows OS type. Because of this bug i need to stick with regexes as following:

```
(schemeModel.getOsType() == SystemTypes.LINUX) ? "\\r\\n" : "[?:^\\r]\\n", 
(schemeModel.getOsType() == SystemTypes.LINUX) ? "\n" : "\r\n")
```

This way, for windows case, only occurrences of '\n' without preceding '\r' are searched and replaced with '\r\n' (regex is modified to find group at '\n' not at [^\r]\n position directly otherwise last letter from line would be extracted as well). Such workflow cannot be implemented using conventional methods thus invalidates this question.

Comment: *"byte array containing platform dependent text"* - If you are working with text, why not use String? Byte arrays are difficult to work with, as you have discovered. How large are the arrays we're talking about?

Comment: My use case need's to use byteArray because i get it as input (reading file from input stream) and need to process it further with `ZipOutputStream` resulting in downloadable Zip in my API. Files have not static size (same size as average Java files) and there are many files like this (from 20 to 100). As mentioned working with String directly results in creation of such Strings (i cannot obtain String directly) and is not acceptable in my case.

Comment: If the regex is your concern, just change `replaceAll` to `replace`.  [The replace method does not use regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: @VGR thanks for response. Didn't notice this. Regex is not my only one problem but this will certainly give me performance improvement.

Comment: @saka1029 i noticed that and it also invalidates answer as well. In windows case i need to search for occurence of '\n' without preceding '\r' and replace it. That cannot be done with conventional method and therefore i will probably stick with regex's anyway.

Comment: I’m still not clear on why you need a byte array.  If the resource is a zip file, the bytes are compressed content and you probably will never see `\n` or `\r\n` (and if you do, it’s coincidence and not an actual newline).

Comment: You can still read out X byte chunks and place them in a String right? If you want to have more control, use `CharsetDecoder`. Then you can possibly read additional bytes in case you have a partial character read in (in e.g. UTF-8). Then, once you have a partial string, replace. You may need some end of chunk handling if you look for a larger string, but that's relatively easy.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes that doesn't have to be more efficient then creating one String at all - highly depends on memory state, N lower allocations can be slower then one allocation of same total memory size. This solution just reduces total memory held by program, but i was looking more into performance efficient way (for that reason didn't want to work with Strings reallocating same memory)

Comment: @VGR once the zip file is extracted it contains same line endings as was encoded into it. My API needs to create ZIP file for certain OS type provided by requester of operation. Persisting windows line endings, zipping file, sending it over API and then extracting it on Linux would still persist Windows line endings for example.

Comment: Meh, while this is true, it will mainly add something of CPU power (of which you generally have plenty) and use cacheable sizes of memory. I'd first try and see if it fits. Otherwise you can always search for the ASCII byte values I suppose, I don't see how that is difficult and why that cannot be performed "manually". I'd do that using a state machine inside a filter stream myself.

Comment: So your goal is to take a zip file as input, fix the line endings in each zip entry whose content is text, and create a new zip file as output?

Comment: Yep, just not taking zip file as input but just regular files (.txt, .java, .properties etc.) the problem is that line endings inside these files vary (Windows, Linux) therefore i cannot use system to deduce line endings and need to send zip files with all line endings correct for certain OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re reading text, you should treat it as text, not as bytes.  Use a [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read the lines one by one, and insert your own newline sequences.

```
String newline = schemeModel.getOsType() == SystemTypes.LINUX ? "\n" : "\r\n";

OutputStream out = /* ... */;

try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:File.txt").getInputStream(),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.write(line);
        writer.write(newline);
    }
}
```

No byte array needed, and you are using only a small amount of memory—the amount needed to hold the largest line encountered.  (I rarely see text with a line longer than one kilobyte, but even one megabyte would be a pretty small memory requirement.)

If you are “fixing” zip entries, the OutputStream can be a ZipOutputStream pointing to a new ZipEntry:

```
String newline = schemeModel.getOsType() == SystemTypes.LINUX ? "\n" : "\r\n";

ZipInputStream oldZip = /* ... */;
ZipOutputStream newZip = /* ... */;

ZipEntry entry;
while ((entry = oldZip.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    newZip.putNextEntry(entry);

    // We only want to fix line endings in text files.
    if (!entry.getName().matches(".*\\." +
        "(?i:txt|x?html?|xml|json|[ch]|cpp|cs|py|java|properties|jsp)")) {

        oldZip.transferTo(newZip);
        continue;
    }

    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(newZip, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oldZip, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.write(line);
        writer.write(newline);
    }

    writer.flush();
}
```

Some notes:

- Are you deliberately ignoring Macs (and other operating systems which are neither Windows nor Linux)?  You should assume `\n` for everything except Windows.  That is, `schemeModel.getOsType() == SystemTypes.WINDOWS ? "\r\n" : "\n"`
- Your code contains `new String(byteArray)` which assumes the bytes of your resource use the default Charset of the system on which your program is running.  I suspect this is not what you intended;  I have added `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` to the construction of the InputStreamReader to address this.  If you really meant to read the bytes using the default Charset, you can remove that second constructor argument.

Comment: @saka1029 UTF-8 is usually the best default.  Far more systems use UTF-8 than use ISO-8859-x now.

Comment: This is good solution in my eyes since line delimiters are easily reworked. Currently using `InputStreamReader` with `ByteArrayInputStream` over my byte arrays since my project is too large to rework immediately. I am getting expected results.

Comment: @saka1029 A one-byte charset can only handle 256 characters.  It can’t possibly handle all of the characters UTF-8 can.  And, again, it is extremely likely that any non-Windows system will be using UTF-8.

Comment: @saka1029 You do know that a Java String is not like a C string, and is never a suitable container for arbitrary bytes, right?